# What is Gradle's $rootDir/gradle directory for?

Tags: gradle, build

What is `$rootDir/gradle` directory for (not .gradle)? Is anything from this directory read by default during a build? Is there a convention regarding what should be put in this directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `gradle` directory is used to store a distributed version of a Gradle wrapper also it has **become some sort of convention** to put most of the common scripts that are used in sub projects, which then can be extended, in an example:

`repositories.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "http://nexus"
    }
}
```

therefore each sub project doesn't need to have this in its script and you can just

```
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/repositories.gradle"
```

or let's say you have some java specific things you don't want to flood your main scripts with etc.

It keeps things clean and more readable, rather than having everything in 1 script and scroll through it forever.

it can also hold configuration properties, JUnit config, log4j config, and so on, basically everything you want, in an example:

`environment.groovy`

```
oracle {
  home = "C:/"   
  tablespace = "TABLE"
  dbaUser = "user"
  dbaPassword = "psswrd"
}
```

---

The folder itself is not 'special' the special folder is `buildSrc` which Gradle reads before it even starts evaluating your scripts, this is the place to create some custom tasks, plugins etc.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've seen only two uses of this directory:

1) Gradle wrapper uses it to store wrapper JAR file along with some properties.

2) In "Gradle In Action" the author uses this directory to store properties in `versioning.gradle` for hand-written versioning plugin and then uses it like this:

```
allprojects {
...
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/versioning.gradle"
}
```

It seems it's a good place to keep build plugins' properties that are not strictly related to a particular project and which should be checked in to the repository.